# joomla displaying full article on different page/Directory then home

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla, on my site I have three sub menus, and I assign blog layout page to third sub menu, I have SEO friendly URL enable.
Now Blog page is showing fine on third directory, eg:

_http://www.mysite.com/home/extra/articles

but when I click on read more option on blog layout page, it display full article on homepage

_http://www.mysite.com/home/82-articletitle

How can I show article on third submenu like or third directory:

_http://www.mysite.com/home/extra/articles/82-articletitle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree/silo structure is made in Joomla by use of sections and categories.
Your article should be placed in categroy, which should be part of section.
Then you make your menu out of sections and categories like this

```
home
-section=extra
--category=articles
---article=82-article
```

Check out this article withe Joomla content structure overview:
[joomla structure pdf](http://www.theartofjoomla.com/joomla-structure-pdf.html)

Comment: thanks, this work for me, I created.
-section=extra
--category=articles
---article=82-article
and then change blog layout from section blog layout to category blog layout, and not it duse exactly what i wanted, thank you verymuch.